# GAMs with residual autocorrelation

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, generalized-additive-model

I am fitting a GAM to data of capture success using the `mgcv` package in R. Given that I have a value of capture success for each of 58 different trapping sites from 2005 to 2014, I have 58 observations in my dataset.
The independent variables are proportions of land cover types. 
I logit-transformed the proportion of anthropogenic areas and wetlands for stabilizing the variance. So, the output of the GAM includes the logit-transformation.

```
function(p) { log(p/(1-p)) }
```

To built the GAM, I used proportions of land cover types which were calculated within trapping sites.

Here are the output of my model:

> summary(mod)

```
Family: Gamma 
Link function: log 

Formula:
capt_succ ~ s(p_urban, k = -1, bs = "cs") + 
    s(p_crop, k = -1, bs = "cs") + s(p_forest, k = -1, 
    bs = "cs") + s(p_wetland, k = -1, bs = "cs") + s(p_grassland, 
    k = -1, bs = "cs")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.55181    0.01436   177.7   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf        Ref.df    F        p-value    
s(p_urban)        8.256      9         21.508   6.70e-16 ***
s(p_crop)         7.077      9         8.855    3.22e-07 ***
s(p_forest)       8.523      9         20.536   3.18e-15 ***
s(p_wetland)      8.068      9         5.782    0.000124 ***
s(p_grassland)    8.195      9         8.585    1.12e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.907   Deviance explained = 97.1%
GCV = 0.040875  Scale est. = 0.011957  n = 58
```

The residual plots were acceptable using the function `gam.check()`.

[image]

However, I found autocorrelation of the residuals.

```
acf(residuals(mod))
pacf(residuals(mod))
```

[image]

In my case, is it worrying ? If yes, how can I resolve residual autocorrelation ?

Comment: The autocorrelation appears to be rather weak and I would probably neglect it. Do you have a reason to believe a substantial negative autocorrelation for a lag of 4 years? Anyway, a `gam` model can be coupled with an `lme` model, which has autocorrelation structures implemented. See `help("gamm")`.

Comment: Thanks very much Roland ! What covariate should I add in the autocorrelation structure ? I tested  `correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1|fyear)` where "fyear" is a factor. I obtain a R-sq.(adj) =  0.172 and only one covariate is significant. In addition, the homogeneity of residual variance is less good. I don't have repeated measures in my dataset. Thanks for your help !

Comment: You probably have spatial correlation. Thus, you should try `corGaus` with spatial coordinates. You could also try `corCAR` with a time covariate.

Comment: Thanks very much Roland ! I don't have spatial coordinates for each observation (i.e., for each trapping site). However, I can define the centroid coordinates of each trapping site (the sites are polygons). Is it correct ? I tested `corCAR1(form = ~ 1|fyear)`. The R-sq.(adj) =  0.148. None covariate was significant. I also tested corCAR1(form = ~ year) where year is a continuous variable but I have this error message: covariate must have unique values within groups for "corCAR1" objects. Thanks very much for your help !